# ¿Se puede hacer una app que se conecte a una base de datos de postgresql?

Tags: android-studio, postgresql

Hola me gustaría saber si puedo realizar una conexión a una base de datos de postgresql en la app que estoy realizando con android studio. Gracias

Comment: Sí se puede. Más info en http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/

Comment: Como te dicen en la respuesta de @aleix, lo mejor y más seguro es que realices las consultas a la base de datos a través de un servicio web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, esto no es una respuesta estricta a tu pregunta, son más bien sugerencias:

Puedes [conectarte](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) a una base de datos [PostgreSQL vía JDBC para Android](http://www.pgcon.org/2011/schedule/attachments/194_pgcon2011-pgdroid.pdf). Pero mi sugerencia es que intentes **no utilizar JDBC directamente desde el dispositivo Android**. Te ahorrarás muchas molestias.

## 1. Desventajas de conectar directamente a una DB

Básicamente, si la conexión se hace desde un dispositivo con mala conectividad, no se recomienda realizar una conexión persistente, en su lugar habría que utilizar solicitudes [HTTP sin estado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sin_estado) ([stateless HTTP requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)).

Es decir, servicios web, de esta forma podremos proporcionar servicios CRUD.

Otras desventajas:

- El pool de conexiones a través de varios dispositivos Android
  **dificulta su monitorización** y la capacidad de limitarlos.
- Los resultados enviados desde la DB a android **consumirán mucho ancho
  de banda** y energía de la batería.
- Exponer su base de datos directamente al cliente tiene **riesgos de
  seguridad**.

## 2. Beneficios de un servicio web.

Los principales beneficios de un servicio web:

- Tiene **conexiones de corta duración con un estado mínimo**, por lo que es fácil volver a donde estaba cuando el dispositivo cambia de redes WiFi a red móvil y viceversa (ya quepierde brevemente la conectividad).
- Pueden pasar por la mayoría de los **proxies web**

## 3. Recomendación

Escribe tu lógica de base de datos en un **servidor de aplicaciones accesible desde la web y comunicate con ese servidor de aplicaciones a través de HTTP + JSON, SOAP, XML-RPC o similar.** Esto hará mucho más eficiente el uso del ancho de banda y la aplicación será más tolerante a los problemas con la conectividad.

También **te ahorra tener que exponer su servidor de base de datos** directamente a Internet - que realmente a día de hoy no debería ser una preocupación con PostgreSQL (siempre que utilices SSL), pero mejor no arriesgarse a hacerlo.